# Printing a bitmap on a TSC printer

Tags: android, printing, bitmap, thermal-printer, tspl

I try to print image on `tsc tdp-225 printer` using the android device via OTG.

This is example from documentation for printing simple bitmap image on `tsc printer`
[image].

This is my implementation
[image].

And this is what the printer has printed

[image]

Maybe someone has already encountered this problem. Printing a monochromatic bitmap using PUTBMP also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun String.hexStringToByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val hexStr = this.replace("-", "")

    var result = ByteArray(hexStr.length / 2, {0})

    for(i in 0 until hexStr.length step 2) {
        val hex = hexStr.substring(i, i + 2)
        val byte: Byte = Integer.valueOf(hex, 16).toByte()
        Log.d(TAG, "hex: $hex; byte: $byte\n")
        result[ i / 2] = byte
    }

    return result
}
```

I should convert hex string to byte array. Anyway propblem with printing via PUTBMP command is still exists. Propblem with uploading bitmap to printer with command DOWNLOAD F.

**UPDATE**

If it is still relevant, I use the following implementation for printing bitmap image

```
fun bitmapCommand(byteArray: ByteArray) {
    _connectionManager.sendMessage("CLS\n\r".toByteArray())
    _connectionManager.sendMessage("BITMAP 0,0,${_labelWidthPxl / 8},$_labelHeightPxl,0,".toByteArray())
    _connectionManager.sendMessage(byteArray)
    _connectionManager.sendMessage("\n\r".toByteArray())
    _connectionManager.sendMessage("PRINT 1,1\n\r".toByteArray())
}
```

The first two commands are preparatory. Third command prints a bitmap pixel by pixel

Comment: Hello. I decided to print serial bmp image via BITMAP command. For me PUTBMP is not suitable for printing several images

Comment: How do you pass the byte array to `sendcommand` where you normally pass strings?

Comment: @TheStoryCoder hello! I updated my answer if it is still relevant for you

Comment: I know this is an old post but I am having the same issues. I have tried converting to byte array then converting that byte array to a string. use bitconverter. Nothing I try seems to work. Did you convert your images to monochrome.